# Azure cron scheduled pipeline always running (without failing builds)

Tags: azure-devops, cron

Azure scheduled pipeline runs for every push in master.
What am I missing?
Here's the yaml code:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 23 * * *"
  displayName: Nightly build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

Apparently, the previous builds aren't failing.
I've already tried to remove this pipeline and create it again, but it keeps running for every push.

[image]

The scheduled runs are correct:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured this out.
Just added the following lines to the yml file and it no longer runs the scheduled pipeline on every push.

```
trigger: none

pr: none
```